# Use CONDITIONAL or INTERSECTION in this scenario?

Tags: probability

Scenario is:

Let's say that 3% of the population drive drunk. (No idea -- just for illustration purposes).

Let's say that one weekend, the cops pull over 10% of drivers and breath test them.

Is the expected number of drunk drivers busted out of 1000 simply 1000 x (.1 X .03) = 3. (An intersection?)

I'm thinking it is correct because being drunk and getting pulled over are independent events. Have I got that right, or should I be looking at this as a conditional probability?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various issues.  In particular, apart from the independence of driving drunk and getting pulled over (let's suppose that testing is truly random), you should be clear what you mean when you say "out of $1000$" and why.

If you meant that of $1000$ drivers in total, $3$ will be busted for drunk driving, then your calculation of $3$ is correct, but "$3$ out of $1000$" is not a particularly meaningful proportion unless you are wondering how many busts there will be.

If you are interested in the expected proportion of drivers driving drunk who are busted, then it is $3$ out of $30$, the same as the proportion of drivers tested.

If you are interested in the expected proportion of tested drivers who are busted, then it is $3$ out of $100$, the same as the proportion of drivers driving drunk.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation, Henry. I chose "out of 1000" for convenience -- I was after an expected number from total drivers tested.